# Refer to a cell on another sheet using the contents of another cell

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with many sheets.

Each sheet contains some raw data in two columns. The first column is the item (name in text) and the second is the value (number).

I like to draw a graph which shows how one item evolves. So I have created a new sheet and started making references to all raw data sheets to the item in interrest.

Doing this manually takes a long time for two reasons:

a) There is many raw-data sheets

b) The item is not on the same row in all raw-data sheets

So I'm wondering if it is possible to make a macro that would fetch all the values. If I gave the macro the item, e.g. `apples`, the macro would search all raw data sheets, find the row containing item `apples` and copy the value to a new row in my graph-sheet.

Is it doable? And how would I start writing such a macro?

Note: I'm not asking for a complete solution. I'm asking for names of functions that would be useful. Example: Which function can I use to iterate over all raw data sheets, which function can I use to find the item in each raw data sheet and so on.

> Updates after comments

Yes, the item names are always in the same column, i.e. A. The value is always in column B (in the same row). But the row number may change from sheet to sheet.

It is only the value I want to copy (i.e. from column B in the row where column A contains the item name I'm interrested in.

Comment: Is `apples` in the same **column** in all sheets ??

Comment: do you want to copy the entire `apple` row or only some values in that row ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Master As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim GotIt As Range, r As Range, K As Long
    Set Master = Sheets("Master")
    arr = Array("raw1", "raw2", "raw3")
    K = 1

    For Each a In arr
        Set sh = Sheets(a)
        Set r = sh.Range("A:A").Cells
        Set GotIt = r.Find(What:="apples", after:=r(1))
        If GotIt Is Nothing Then
        Else
            GotIt.Resize(1, 2).Copy Master.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

Where `arr` is the array of sheet names of the raw data sheets and `Master` is the name of the summary worksheet.

Comment: It works perfectly - thanks, you saved me a lot of time and I learned some Excel coding as well. Great.